# How to add pear to my project

Tags: php, pear

Right now I am using PEAR on local host and it is installed in the PHP folder. I changed include_path and used PEAR and there is no problem. But I'm working on my own framework which i want to be an standalone folder. lets say i want to install my framework on 10 WebServers. Do i need to install PEAR 10 times for all Servers ?

Is there an easier way to combine pear into my project as i want it to be an standalone folder.

Can i just simply copy pear folder to my project folder and include it from there ? or i need to install pear every time i want to use is ?

Thanks for reading my question

Comment: I believe PEAR is package manager and you don't need to install everytime

Comment: @NaingLinAung i know but for example i'm using mail package right now. it is installed in my php folder/share. there are lots of files including pear,pear5 and so on. i don't know which of them should i copy to my project. I think pear lacks a good documentation or i misunderstood something

Comment: Yes, that why most ppl use composer instead in IMO

Comment: PEAR seems to coming to the end of its useful like. It appears to be replaced by Composer/Packagist and a few other code delivery mechanisms

Comment: Oh yes, but just out of interest i want to experiment with PEAR. i have no problem using it offline but for example we have a portal which we want to use some PEAR packages in it. My question is does every customer needs to install pear separately ? Is there a way to combine PEAR with our portal in order to makes installation easier ? I know PEAR.php and PEAR5.php are necessary for using Packages but is that all ? pear.php and pear5.php and the package ?

Comment: NoBody answers my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pear project-local just like composer. Those files can be checked in and distributed with your software:

```
$ pear config-create `pwd` pear.conf
$ pear -c pear.conf install http_request2
```

Now you just have to set the include path to `$dir/pear/php/` and that's it.

Whenever you need to upgrade/install, use `pear -c pear.conf $command`.

Comment: Thanks for you help, let's say i have `project/root/pear` so how can i force pear installer to put all my pear packages and so on into `project/root/pear` ?

Answer (score 2):

In theory you can download the PEAR packages, gunzip them and use them in your projects, but you would then lose all dependency handling and maintaining the library would be hard.

I'd recommend using PEAR package manager on your sites. You could just create your own script to run the required pear commands?

An alternative could be to find your helper classes elsewhere like i.e. [phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/)